How to Render Validation Messages from DTO in Thymeleaf View?
I am working on a Spring Boot project where I want to display validation error messages defined in my DTO directly on the view using Thymeleaf, especially the "content" field. While the validation itself works correctly, the issue is that the error messages defined in the @NotEmpty and @Size annotations in my DTO are not rendered in the view.
Entity:
package io.github.haebin827.hiphopreview.kr.domain;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Getter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Feedback {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String content;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime regDate;

    @PrePersist
    protected void onCreate() {
        this.regDate = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}

DTO:
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FeedbackDTO {
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Content is required.")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 1000, message = "Content should be less than 1000 letters")
    private String content;

    private LocalDateTime regDate;
}

Controller:
@GetMapping("/feedback")
    public void feedbackGET(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("feedback", new Feedback());
    }

    @PostMapping("/feedback")
    public String feedbackPOST(@Valid @ModelAttribute("feedbackDTO") FeedbackDTO feedbackDTO, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "support/feedback";
        }

        // All the logics to save DTO to the database

        return "redirect:/support/feedback";
    }

View:
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      layout:decorate="~{layout/base.html}">

<div layout:fragment="content" class="col-9 mx-auto" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 100px; margin-bottom: 150px;">
    <div>
        <h3 class="mb-2" style="display: inline-block; color: #333;">Sending a feedback</h3>
        <hr class="mb-6" style="margin-bottom: 40px; margin-top: 40px; border: 1px solid #555;">
        <form id="feedbackForm"
              th:action="@{/support/feedback}"
              th:object="${feedbackDTO}"
              method="post"
              style="text-align: left;"
              class="col-8 mx-auto" novalidate>

            <div class="row mb-4">
                <label for="content" class="col-md-3 col-form-label text-md-end font-weight-bold">
                    Content <span style="color: red;">*</span>:
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <textarea id="content"
                              name="content"
                              class="form-control"
                              rows="4"
                              th:field="*{content}"
                              required></textarea>
                    <div class="item field invalid" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('content')}" th:errors="*{content}">
                        <!-- DTO message will be appeared here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Submit button -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9 offset-md-3 text-end">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark rounded-pill">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script layout:fragment="script" th:inline="javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        const form = document.getElementById('feedbackForm');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
            form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
    });
</script>
</html>

The validation works correctly (e.g., the form submission is blocked if a field is empty), but the error messages defined in the @NotEmpty and @Size annotations are not rendered in the view. Instead, the  elements meant to display the errors remain empty.
What could be the issue? Am I missing a step in connecting the validation error messages to the view?
Any guidance or corrections would be greatly appreciated.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Shouldn't you be using <p> instead of <div> for this to work?

Your controller is not using the DTO it is usint the entity, so no validation rules apply here.

Ah my bad. I revised the code to use DTO correctly. Since the DTO wasn't working, I also tried using the Entity directly but neither approach worked. I also tried using the  tag as suggested, but it still doesn't work.

Maybe have a look to Form handling with Thymeleaf on how to show validation messages? I don't quite get why you have that JavaScript snippet there?
